# Setting variables in PHP class

Tags: php, oop, api, class, curl

I've inherited a bit of code that is used to integrate with a third party (Highrise CRM). I'm a bit rusty on this side of PHP, so was looking for some help.

I want to assign a session variable within a class. At the moment I have the following code:

```
var $highrise_url = 'https://example.highrisehq.com';
var $api_token = 'foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo';
var $task_assignee_user_id = 'foofoo';
```

But I want the URL, token and ID to be set based on the session valuables I pull from the database of the user who is logged in i.e.

```
$_SESSION['hrurl']
$_SESSION['hrapi']
$_SESSION['hrid']
```

The class uses the variables set above in functions like:

```
$curl = curl_init($this->highrise_url.'/deals.xml');
```

I know that I CAN'T set a variable in a class like this:

```
var $highrise_url = $_SESSION['hrurl'];
```

So how do I do it?

I believe it's done by using the construct function, but I'm shaky at best, so would appreciate help :o)

Many thanks,

Gregor

Comment: Do you have a constructor? Put it there.

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to match your question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

```
class A
{
    public $highrise_url;
    public $api_token;
    public $task_assignee_user_id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->highrise_url = $_SESSION['hrurl'];
        $this->api_token = $_SESSION['hrapi'];
        $this->task_assignee_user_id = $_SESSION['hrid'];
    }
}

$a = new A();
```

A better solution may be to pass the values to the constructor:

```
public function __construct($highrise_url, $api_token, $task_assignee_user_id)
{
    $this->highrise_url = $highrise_url;
    $this->api_token = $api_token;
    $this->task_assignee_user_id = $task_assignee_user_id;
}

...

$a = new A($_SESSION['hrurl'], $_SESSION['hrapi'], $_SESSION['hrid']);
```

The second way cuts down on [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) between your class and the `$_SESSION` array. That way you can use (or test) the class without relying on session functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Set it in the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

```
class HighriseClass {
  var $highrise_url;

  function __construct() {
    $this->highrise_url = $_SESSION['hrurl'];
  }
}
```